# Generic Class with Constraint access issue

Tags: java, android

This a general JAVA question. In android, there is an interface [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html):

This is an example inside the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html):

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

We are required to implement the 2 functions `describeContents()` and `writeToParcel`.

***(problem)***
Besides them, we are also required to implement the `Parcelable.Creator<T>` interface as a static field called CREATOR.

Everything is actually straight forward. Now I want to create a Generic Class that has a Parcelable Class Type:

```
public class ShushContainer<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable
```

I am able to implement Parcelable. I can call the `T`'s `writeToParcel` function. However, I am unable to access the static CREATOR field.

```
public class ShushContainer<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable {
    Vector<T> items;
    String someField;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(someField);
        dest.writeInt(items.size());
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
            items.get(i).writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    }

    public ShushContainer(Parcel in) {
        someField = in.readString();
        int size = in.readInt();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            //this does not work
            items.add(T.CREATOR.createFromParcel(in));
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ShushContainer> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ShushContainer>() {
        public ShushContainer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ShushContainer(in);
        }

        public ShushContainer[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ShushContainer[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `<T extends Parcelable>` you need `<T extends ShushContainer<T> & Parcelable>` this way you specify that `T` is `ShushContainer` so you can access is methods and variables.

```
public class ShushContainer<T extends ShushContainer<T> & Parcelable> 
implements Parcelable
```

Here is the example using `Serializable`

```
class Sample<T extends Sample<T> & Serializable> implements Serializable {

  public static int CONST = 0;

   public void foo()
   {
     T.CONST = 5;
   }
}
```

**Update**

If I understand correctly threre is another class which implements `Parcelable` which has `CREATOR`
You are trying dynamic polymorphism for Static variables which is not possible.

Sample example to show how it fails

```
public class Base {
    public static int count = 10;
}

public class Child extends Base {
    public static int count = 20;
}


class Sample<T extends Base> {
    T t = null;
    public void printCount() {
        System.out.println(T.count);
    }
    public Sample(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample<Child> sample = new Sample<Child>(new Child());
        Sample<Base> sample1 = new Sample<Base>(new Base());
        sample.printCount();//Child value printed as 10
        sample1.printCount();//Same for parent value printed as  10
    }

}
```

This program fails because static fields are bound to Class rather than instance so there are two separate `count` one for `Base` and one for `Child` if you access value of `Base` then it will always be 10.

**You can use reflection to check whether `CREATOR` field is present and access it.Which will not be possible without object or class object.**

Or You can do something like below using [TypeToken](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/smartshop-project/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java.htm)

```
class Sample<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    public int abc = 0;
    public void foo() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        TypeToken<Sample<Integer>> token = new TypeToken<Sample<Integer>>() {
        };
        Class<?> t = token.getRawType();
        Field field = t.getDeclaredField("abc");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(field.getName());

    }
}
```

Comment: T is another Class that implements Parcelable.

Comment: Then how can that class have `CREATOR` because it is defined in ShushContainer. This variable belongs to this class only. Simply use it why do you need T.CREATOR Just use CREATOR

Comment: Nopes ShushContainer implements Parcelable and has its own CREATOR. T also implements Parcelable and has its own CREATOR. It is this CREATOR that I'm unable to access.

Comment: `Parcelable.Creator` is an interface there is no variable as `CREATOR` check the [Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/os/Parcelable.java). Now if your custom class which has CREATOR variable and if you want to access that then you will need another base class which will have this variable defined and T should extend from that other wise T will be always Parcelable  and you will not able to access it.

Comment: But the system is somehow able to access this CREATOR and when it does not find it, it throws an exception.

Comment: The only way such restriction can be added is Using `Reflection`. Check the field name of class which implements `Parcelable` if there is no field name `CREATOR` throw exception.

Comment: Oh. Maybe We should get the CREATOR instance by Reflection keeping in mind it is a TYPE!

Comment: I have the same problem. did you succeed in solving the issue @SherifelKhatib?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question as to how to access the static CREATOR property, however you do not need to access this property implement Parcelable. See below for example:

```
public class TestModel<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable {

private List<T> items;
private String someField;

public List<T> items() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<T> newValue) {
    items = newValue;
}

public String someField() {
    return someField;
}

public void setSomeField(String newValue) {
    someField = newValue;
}

//region: Parcelable implementation

public TestModel(Parcel in) {
    someField = in.readString();

    int size = in.readInt();
    if (size == 0) {
        items = null;
    }

    else {

        Class<?> type = (Class<?>) in.readSerializable();

        items = new ArrayList<>(size);
        in.readList(items, type.getClassLoader());
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(someField);

    if (items == null || items.size() == 0)
        dest.writeInt(0);

    else {
        dest.writeInt(items.size());

        final Class<?> objectsType = items.get(0).getClass();
        dest.writeSerializable(objectsType);

        dest.writeList(items);
    }

    dest.writeInt(items.size());
    for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
        items.get(i).writeToParcel(dest, flags);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<TestModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TestModel>() {
    public TestModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new TestModel(in);
    }

    public TestModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TestModel[size];
    }
};

//endregion
}
```