# Can I create a generic type in a kotlin data class?

Tags: generics, kotlin, parcelable, data-class

I have a backend that will always return either a "success" with some data, as in the json field field will be named success and have the data in it. Or it will return an error object in a json format.
So I'd like to have some sort of BaseResponse, so when I use it I could do something like BaseResponse so the success will be mapped as a Person object.

So I was thinking of doing like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class BaseResponse<T>(
     val success: T? = null
) : Parcelable
```

But it says Type is not directly supported with Parcelize. Is there any way I can do this at all? Or do I need to write something custom? The calls etc are called using Retrofit and Gson as serializer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to parcel a generic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797399/is-it-possible-to-parcel-a-generic-class)

Comment: It doesn't seem to take into account that it's data classes I need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do so by requiring `T` to be an implementation of `Parcelable`, like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class BaseResponse<T: Parcelable>(val success: T? = null) : Parcelable
```

Comment: This does not compile with the error  "non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: this solution is not working for me. Throws an error "non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context". is there anything else?